# Can we add a footer that is always visible when expanded in React Fluent UI dropdown

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

My requirement is to make an option render at the bottom of the fluent ui dropdown and make it stick there(always visible when expanded) even if there is an overflow and the scroll is enabled on the dropdown.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to offer a solution, but you might want to start here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69999081/how-do-i-create-a-sticky-non-scrollable-header-footer-in-a-fluentui-modal-cont